# r - subset dataframe where field in array

Tags: r, subset

Is it possible in R to create a subset function where it checks if a column value is in a list of items.

This may look something like (I've checked and this doesn't work):

```
sub <- subset(data, field IN c(1,2,3))
```

Comment: Replace `IN` with `%in%`

Comment: `data[ data$field %in% c(1,2,3), ]`

Comment: great, thanks Hadd

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', set the `key` column and subset the rows based on the vector of values (`.(1:3)`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data, key="field")[.(1:3), nomatch=0]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(48)
data <- data.frame(field = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE), value = rnorm(10))
```